# Template template parameter with default values unknown

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function that takes a container as a parameter
(I use this function for both vector, set, map so trying to avoid it would cost a lot of code copying)
so naturally I declared it as:

```
template<template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class 
Container> Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

Note that the return value of `Foo` uses the default parameter of the container.

When I use the function with vector, list or set it works just fine;
the problem I have is when I try to use this template with a map container with the comparator and value type fixed (which is defined as `MapToValue<ValueType>::FromKey` with `A` and `Comparator<Key>` already defined):

```
template<class Value> class MapToValue {
     template<class Key, class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const 
     Key, Value>>> FromKey : public std::map<Key, Value, Comparator<Key>, 
     Allocator> {...}
```

In this case the default value of the allocator is diffrent then the one in the definition of `Foo` - `std::allocator<std::pair<_Ty, std::string>>` vs. `std::allocator<_Ty>`.

Long story short, I need that to send to `Foo` a container with a second parameter that can be defaulted WITHOUT knowing what this default type would be (so this function template can be used for both map, vector or basically any other container). Is this possible?

EDIT: I cannot use C++11 in any way, the compiler is gcc 4.1.2 (out of my control)

Comment: What is `A` in `weak_ptr<A>`?

Comment: I believe what you're trying is overly verbose and probably overkill for a simpler operation. Anyway your problem is of course caused by the fact containers have different parameters: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd9e6cc703c5e1ae . I wouldn't write code like this (take it as an example)

Comment: @MarcoA. When I wrap both the map and the set in some class they all fit the same template:
template<class T, class Allocator = ***Unknown default type***>

Answer (score 1):

In c++11 you can take any template as template argument:

```
template<template <class ...> class Container>
Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

Comment: What is `A` in `std::weak_ptr<A>`?

Comment: This type was used by OP in his question.

Comment: I just added I cannot use C++11, I wish I could :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a misunderstanding here of how template template parameters operate. This declaration:

```
template<template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class Container> 
Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

Is just an overly verbose version of this declaration:

```
template < template <class, class> class Container> 
Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

(What is `A` btw?)

It doesn't matter what the names or defaults of the types are that `Container` takes - `Foo` is simply templated on some class template that takes two template type arguments. That works with [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) because it is a class template that takes two template type arguments:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

It does not work with [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) because that one takes four template type arguments:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

In C++11, you can generalize your function to have a template template argument take an arbitrary number of template type arguments:

```
template < template <class...> class Container> 
Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

Though, however, this is never going to work as some container types can't be constructed with only a single template argument (e.g. `map`).

Comment: The OP has to deal with a more fundamental problem to his approach. The template parameters for `vector`, `list`, `set`, and `map` are such that you can't use them in `Foo`. `Allocator` is the second template argument for `vector` and `list`. It is the third argument for `set`. It is the fourth argument for `map`.

Comment: A is just some class;
I defined a specific type that inherits from std::map with only 2 template parameters and with this type it has the problem;
Because I use the default parameter in the definition of Foo I must have a default value for it (otherwise the compiler screams), the question is whether I can do it without specifying what this default type is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it isn't elegant but it works:
Sending to `Foo` another template argument that would be the way to deafault the Allocator:

```
template<template<typename> class DefaultAllocator, template<typename T, 
typename Allocator = DefaultAllocator<T>> class Container>
Container<std::weak_ptr<A>>* Foo() {...}
```

This way I send `Foo<std::allocator,std::vector>` all the same.
Also by creating some wrapper `template<class T> class MapAllocatorWrapper : std::allocator<std::pair<T,std::string>>`, I can send `Foo<MapAllocatorWrapper, MapToType<std::string>::FromKey` after slight adjustments.